# How to copy from a constantly changing path in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How would I get a batch file to copy from a certain directory that contains a file with a name that would be different every time the batch file is run.
Ex.:

```
copy "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"
```

`%USER%` is the changing file name.

Comment: Since there are likely multiple USERS you'll have to have a way to predict what that variable will be.  Will it be based on who runs the batch file?

Comment: It will be based on whomever is logged into the computer, but it will be launched from a USB, ideally. @UltrasoundJelly

Answer (score 2):

```
%username%
```

is the environment variable for the current user's username. and

```
%userprofile%
```

is the path to their profile.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already provided answer, you can get even further down the path using another of the built-in environment variables, %LOCALAPPDATA%.

```dos
"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"
```

Type **SET** followed by **[Enter]** into a cmd.exe window to see all of the machine's variables listed.